# C++ / OpenGL 3.3+: No vertices are being rendered

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, shader

I guess this is the millionth question of the same type. I am using OpenGL 3.3 Core Profile with C++ and try to render a triangle.

I have already read the following two pages, including typing AND copy-pasting the code that is being discussed. Below I posted the significant bits. I already had a triangle being rendered, but obviously I changed some minor detail and messed it up. GLFW and GLEW are being initialized and clearing with the glClearColor works just fine.

Frameworks in use: **GLFW for windowing, GLEW and GLM.**

Question: **What is the error in my code and why is nothing being rendered?**

Expectation: **A white triangle should be visible.**

Result: **Nothing is being rendered. The window is filled with the glClearColor**

Game.cpp

```
const float vertex_data[9] = {
    -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,
     1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,
     0.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
};

void Game::init()
{
    shader = ShaderProgram();
    shader.attachShader(readTextFromFile("data/shaders/main.vs"), GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    shader.attachShader(readTextFromFile("data/shaders/main.fs"), GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    shader.linkProgram();

    mesh = Mesh(vertex_data);
}

void Game::render()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    shader.bind();
    {
        mesh.render();
    }
    shader.unbind();
}
```

Mesh.cpp

```
uint32_t vao;
uint32_t vertex_buffer;

Mesh::Mesh(const float vertex_data[])
{
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
    glBindVertexArray(vao);

    glGenBuffers(1, &vertex_buffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertex_buffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertex_data), vertex_data, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*) 0);
}

void Mesh::render()
{
    glBindVertexArray(vao);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    {
        // Is this actually necessary for every draw-call?
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertex_buffer); 
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
    }
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
}
```

ShaderProgram.cpp

```
uint32 id = 0;
bool linked = false;

uint32 vertex_shader = 0;
uint32 fragment_shader = 0;

ShaderProgram::~ShaderProgram()
{
    unbind();

    if (vertex_shader > 0)
    {
        glDetachShader(id, vertex_shader);
        glDeleteShader(vertex_shader);
    }

    if (fragment_shader > 0)
    {
        glDetachShader(id, fragment_shader);
        glDeleteShader(fragment_shader);
    }

    if (id > 0 && linked)
    {
        glDeleteProgram(id);
    }
}

void ShaderProgram::attachShader(std::string source, int32 type)
{
    assert(type == GL_VERTEX_SHADER || type == GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    assert(id == 0);

    const char* code = source.c_str();

    switch (type)
    {
        case GL_VERTEX_SHADER:
            assert(vertex_shader == 0);

            vertex_shader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
            glShaderSource(vertex_shader, 1, &code, NULL);
            glCompileShader(vertex_shader);

            int32 vresult;
            glGetShaderiv(vertex_shader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &vresult);

            if (vresult != GL_TRUE)
            {
                int32 infolength;
                glGetShaderiv(vertex_shader, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &infolength);

                GLchar* infolog = new GLchar[infolength + 1];
                glGetShaderInfoLog(vertex_shader, infolength + 1, NULL, infolog);

                std::stringstream ss;
                ss << "Shader compilation failed for Vertex Shader: " << infolog << std::endl;

                std::cout << ss.str() << std::endl;

                throw std::runtime_error(ss.str());
            }
            break;
        case GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER:
            assert(fragment_shader == 0);

            fragment_shader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
            glShaderSource(fragment_shader, 1, &code, NULL);
            glCompileShader(fragment_shader);

            int32 fresult;
            glGetShaderiv(fragment_shader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &fresult);

            if (fresult != GL_TRUE)
            {
                int32 infolength;
                glGetShaderiv(fragment_shader, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &infolength);

                int32 infosize = infolength + 1;
                GLchar* infolog = new GLchar[infosize];
                glGetShaderInfoLog(fragment_shader, infosize, NULL, infolog);

                std::stringstream ss;
                ss << "Shader compilation failed for Fragment Shader: " << infolog << std::endl;

                std::cout << ss.str() << std::endl;

                throw std::runtime_error(ss.str());
            }
            break;
        default:
            throw std::invalid_argument("Unknown Shader-Type specified");
    }
}

void ShaderProgram::linkProgram()
{
    assert(id == 0);
    assert(vertex_shader > 0);
    assert(fragment_shader > 0);

    id = glCreateProgram();

    glAttachShader(id, vertex_shader);
    glAttachShader(id, fragment_shader);

    glLinkProgram(id);

    int32 result;
    glGetProgramiv(id, GL_LINK_STATUS, &result);

    if (result != GL_TRUE)
    {
        int32 infolength;
        glGetProgramiv(id, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &infolength);

        int32 infosize = infolength + 1;
        GLchar* infolog = new GLchar[infosize];
        glGetProgramInfoLog(id, infosize, NULL, infolog);

        std::stringstream ss;
        ss << "Shader Program Linking failed: " << infolog << std::endl;

        throw std::runtime_error(ss.str());
    }

    linked = true;
}

void ShaderProgram::bind()
{
    assert(id > 0);
    assert(linked);

    glUseProgram(id);
}

void ShaderProgram::unbind()
{
    int32 current;
    glGetIntegerv(GL_CURRENT_PROGRAM, &current);

    if (current == id)
    {
        glUseProgram(0);
    }
}

bool ShaderProgram::isLinked()
{
    return linked;
}
```

Vertex Shader: "main.vs"

```
#version 330

layout(location = 0) in vec3 VertexPosition;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4(VertexPosition.xyz, 1.0);
}
```

Fragment Shader "main.fs":

```
#version 330

out vec4 FinalColor;

void main()
{
    FinalColor = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
}
```

Comment: What window framework are you using (e.g. `glfw`)?

Comment: @BenSteffan Added to the main post. GLFW for windowing, GLEW and GLM.

Comment: I like how you lay out your problem, what should happen, and everything you use. More questions should use this format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line has an error:

```
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertex_data), vertex_data, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

The second parameter expects the size of the array but you are passing the size of a pointer. To fix it use something like `vertex count * sizeof( float )`

Comment: That was quick! And it is the correct answer. Fixing this makes the triangle appear. I will accept your answer as soon as I can. Any advice on how to automatically retrieve the correct size instead of manually typing sizeof(float) * (vertexcount * 3)?

Comment: @j8a2b0e7 You can store the vertices into an `std::vector` to get the array size instead of using a C-style array, but then you must still multiply by `sizeof( float )`